# remove and add character from string

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

I would like to replace `\n` with a new line.

This is the result from database:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<body>\n<div>\n<label class=\"s20 c03\">Label</label>\n</div>\n</body>\n</html>
```

I want the string to be aesthetically pleasing, for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div>
<label class="s20 c03">Label</label>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so you want to remove the newlines and then add them again?

Comment: the result from the database have a character, i want to remove the special character and display it again in a nice view.

Comment: if your input is as what you show in your question, and you want it to look like your output in the question, you simply have to echo it :D it should end up looking exactly like that. If you want to replace occourences, use `str_replace($search,$replace,$string)`

Comment: Aesthetically pleasing in what context? Do you want to see it in the displayed page or just the page's source (i.e. via View Page Source in a browser)?

Comment: thanks to all but i find my best solution to this problem. i used json decode

Comment: You should share how you solved your problem as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the `\n` are burnt into the string. To replace them with actual newline characters, use this:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('/\\\\n/', '\n', $yourstring);
```

Comment: thanks to all but i find my best solution to this problem. i used json decode

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely find the source of the double escaping first.

To undo your very exact data issue, there is [**`stripcslashes()`**](http://php.net/stripcslashes) however.

- Replaces a literal `\n` with a newline.
- And the `\"` into a plain double quote.

It also undoes `\r` and octal `\000` or hex `\x00` escapes, or (it's most likely that your database also contains these) the double backslash `\\` back into a singular one.

Comment: thanks to all but i find my best solution to this problem. i used json decode

Answer (score 0):

@ahmadalbayati is on the right track I think.

### Pretty Markup

If you just want the database-returned string to look pretty *in the returned page's markup* (i.e. via View Page Source in a browser), simply echo it where you want it in the markup...

```
<?php
$dbResponse = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<body>\n<div>\n<label class=\"s20 c03\">Label</label>\n</div>\n</body>\n</html>";
echo $dbResponse;
?>
```

...which yields the following markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div>
<label class="s20 c03">Label</label>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### Pretty Rendered Page (and Markup)

If you want to show the database-returned string *when the returned page is rendered*, you can use the [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and [`htmlspecialchars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) functions in conjunction as follows...

```
<?php
$dbResponse = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<body>\n<div>\n<label class=\"s20 c03\">Label</label>\n</div>\n</body>\n</html>";
echo str_replace("\n", "<br />\n", htmlspecialchars($dbResponse));
?>
```

..., which yields the following displayed page...

> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
> <body>
> <div>
> <label class="s20 c03">Label</label>
> </div>
> </body>
> </html>

...and the following markup behind it:

```
&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;<br />
&lt;html&gt;<br />
&lt;body&gt;<br />
&lt;div&gt;<br />
&lt;label class=&quot;s20 c03&quot;&gt;Label&lt;/label&gt;<br />
&lt;/div&gt;<br />
&lt;/body&gt;<br />
&lt;/html&gt;
```

Comment: thanks to all but i find my best solution to this problem. i used json decode